Chrome browser tab close missing navigator.sendBEacon() calls some times for some users
In my angular application, on Chrome browser tab close navigator.sendBEacon() calls made on event window:pagehide and window:pagehide. These calls a are missing some times and it is observed since couple of weeks. Any clue ?
Not all user facing this issue though they have same Chrome Version 124.0.6367.119 (Official Build) (64-bit) and this issue sufaced since couple of weeks recently before that it was fine.
Tried to tack the call through Fiddler and no trace in network.

pagehide is a fallback... are you checking visibility api? (visibilitychange?)  You should include your code, and if possible, a repeatable procedure that shows the bug.

@browsermator visibilitychange change is being triggered when I go to a diffrent application and come back. This is not intended, I want it to trigger only when Broser/Tab is closed.
